# Blank screen problem in Ubuntu 15.04 after selecting Ubuntu from GRUB menu

Tags: drivers, grub2, desktop-environments

After I select Ubuntu in the GRUB menu, I get a blank screen. When I select recovery mode in Advanced Options, then it runs fine.

How can I successfully boot Ubuntu normally?

My laptop is:

- HP pavilion g4 notebook series
- 2 GB RAM
- 500 GB HDD
- Dual boot Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also faced this problem. It's because of the graphics driver for your AMD graphics card.

You should try to update and then upgrade through virtual terminal by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.

You may need to reinstall the driver through terminal by searching for the correct package for it. Installing the AMD driver through their official website should be the last resort, as it mostly doesn't work.